# What do I do next?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've bought everything from the shop (Except for the man's hat) and the forge. I've killed the rats in the guy's cellar. What do I do now?

Answer (score 5):

After you kill the rats in the basement, the owner of that house will give you a map of the world. This will make a "Back to the map" button appear. Click it to display the world map and you will be able to leave the village.
[image: Freehand red circles! Woo!]